# Material-UI slider causes massive re-renders

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a slider to control volume. When there one or two accordions in a list below on the same page it renders fast and smooth when the slider is dragged, but as soon as I have a list of accordions below (rendered using react-virtuoso) that is much larger, it slows down awfully and the motion of the slider becomes very jerky.

I did notice that when I hover on the slider dot the whole page re-paints, but it also does this on the mui website too. But dragging the slider dot is simply awful.

I'm using `react-redux` to store the value of the slider and update the volume, but why would it be that the presence of many accordions would slow it down.

I'd add a code sandbox, but I'm having trouble getting it to load MUI nicely. If I get that working, I'll edit and add the link.

[image: React profiler]

I also noted when looking at the performance monitor that the CPU usage appears to go up to 95% while moving the slider as seen by the spikes in this image:
[image: performance monitor CPU spike]

Comment: With the React Profiler you can see why elements rerender, that should probably give you some indication of what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeBrunerie. I did run that, but I can't see anything suspicious in there. The worst is a 4.9ms render time. I've added a screenshot of the profiler result in the question

Comment: Oooo, I do have a bunch of window event listeners for resizing, might they be doing something unwanted? I also noted that the CPU usage in the performance monitor goes through the roof to >90%!

Comment: So I found the root cause, but I just don't understand why it's happening. I added a slider that doesn't have an `onChange` method and it ran super smooth. When I set the  onChange the function to return the same state, it works fast, when I set it to create a shallow copy of the state (`return {...state}` it slows massively. I wonder whether putting a dither on the slider would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the slider, but not because of it.
It was as a result of a poor method employed to get the data for each of the accordion panels where the slider triggered those to recalculate their data. Changing the data structure from an array of objects to an object of objects and grabbing the data by looking for it's own key solved the problem.